# Kubuntu boots up to a blank screen until I drop to a TTY and restart X

Tags: xorg

I have a Kubuntu machine I've been using for around a year and a half, and recently it has started booting up to a blank screen. I cannot get it to show anything by moving the mouse, hitting keys, or anything like that. It's just blank. Once I drop to a TTY and forcefully kill X it restarts and behaves as it should. I'm not sure how I should go about diagnosing or fixing this.

Any advice?